# Getting multiple logs on one line with log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I'm using org.apache.log4j.Logger and I frequently see lines in my log which look like this:

```
2013-06-09T00:06:00,092 data data data dat2013-06-09T00:06:10,253 data data2013-06-09T00:06:16,202 data d2013-06-09T00:06:20,750 data data data data
```

What I expect to see is:

```
2013-06-09T00:06:00,092 data data data data
2013-06-09T00:06:10,253 data data data data
2013-06-09T00:06:16,202 data data data data
2013-06-09T00:06:20,750 data data data data
```

That is, with multiple log-lines crammed together on one line, and log information being overwritten. I've no idea what I'm doing wrong, so I'd like to know (A) if it's something obvious or (B) any pointers that can help me solve this.

My logger class looks like this:

```
public class MyLogger {
    private final org.apache.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("com.example.mylog");

    public void info(String info){
        synchronized (log){
            log.info(info);
        }
    }
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
private CallsLogger callsLogger;
/* ... */
myLogger.info(String.format("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", "data", "data", "data", "data"));
```

I'm logging ~40.000 events per day, and about 200 of these have malformed lines, with anything from 2 to 11 separate events per line.

My log4j.xml looks liks this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/docs/api/org/apache/log4j/xml/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="mylog" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="logs/mylog.log.%d.gz"/>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS}\t%m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.example.mylog" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="mylog"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="appender"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: myLogger.info(String.format("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", "data", "data", "data", "data"+"\n")); try this

Comment: @shreyanshjogi The newline is already in the logging pattern (`%n`).

Comment: it could be a problem with buffering and parallel access to a logger, try to force the logger to flush after every log operation by adding:
 <param name="immediateFlush" value="true"/> in appender tag

Comment: This problem only affects 0.3% of log lines, and 0.9% of events logged.

Comment: Thanks @gawi, I could try using "immediateFlush", but then I lose the advantage of writing in batches, and not hitting the disk on every event.

Comment: you can use my hint just to check if this is the problem @Adam - maybe there are other solutions, I'm not a log4j guru :)

Comment: Adam, log4j is thread safe, and you should not require that extra layer of synchronization in MyLogger, although that would not cause your problem.   Are you sure only one process is writing to your log?  If you have several processes on the same machine (or several processes on different machines writing to shared disk) with the same log4j config, JVM-level synchronization won't protect your log, and you will see symptoms like you describe.

Answer (score 1):

```
<param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %m%n"/>
```

Try the above pattern without \t

OR

Comment: or if u need the tab replace \t with &#9; and give it a try. According to me %t is used to display the thread name

Answer (score 1):

Use a class like

```
public class MyPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {
...
public String format(LoggingEvent pEvent) {
    return super.format(pEvent).replace('\n', ' ') + '\n';
}
...
```

This will remove all \n from the string to be logged and then add one at the end of the line.

And in the log4j config xml use:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
...
<layout class="....MyPatternLayout">
...
</layout>
</appender>
```